# How to run metric_fu command on a specific task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metrics, metric-fu

`rake metrics:all` seems to generate all metric reports as flog,flay..etc. How to run report for a single metric (say flog) `rake metrics:flog` The following error occurs while running this command

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'metrics:flog'
```

Answer (score 0):

metric_fu 3.0 is now out and lets you do this from either the command-line or via a '.metrics' file  (I'm the maintainer).  https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu  e.g. you could run

```
metric_fu -r --no-flay --no-reek --no-saikuro --no-churn --no-roodi --no-rcov
```